# Powershell change property name on output

Tags: powershell

I have the following working code:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Staff' | 
    
    Where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'} | 
        
        Get-ADUSer -properties name, employeenumber |
            
            Where { $_.Enabled -eq $True} |
               
                Select-Object employeeNumber, @{n="first_name";e={$_.GivenName}}, @{n="last_name";e={$_.Surname}}, @{n="UserStates.short_name";e={"1"}}, @{n="email_address";e={$_.UserPrincipalName}}, @{n="Sites.short_name";e={"Office"}}, @{n="job_title";e={""}}
```

I want to change the name of `employeeNumber` but when I use the format used on the other properties, I don't get any output...like this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Staff' | 
    
    Where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'} | 
        
        Get-ADUSer -properties name, employeenumber |
            
            Where { $_.Enabled -eq $True} |
               
                Select-Object @{n="external_id";e={$_.employeeNumber}}, @{n="first_name";e={$_.GivenName}}, @{n="last_name";e={$_.Surname}}, @{n="UserStates.short_name";e={"1"}}, @{n="email_address";e={$_.UserPrincipalName}}, @{n="Sites.short_name";e={"Office"}}, @{n="job_title";e={""}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me. Try restarting your Powershell session.

Comment: I ran this: `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | Where-Object ObjectClass -eq 'user' | Get-ADUser -Properties Name, EmployeeNumber, Enabled, GivenName, Surname, UserPrincipalName | Where-Object Enabled -eq $true | Select-Object -Property @{n="external_id";e={$_.employeeNumber}}, @{n="first_name";e={$_.GivenName}}, @{n="last_name";e={$_.Surname}}, @{n="UserStates.short_name";e={"1"}}, @{n="email_address";e={$_.UserPrincipalName}}, @{n="Sites.short_name";e={"Office"}}, @{n="job_title";e={""}}`

Comment: @BaconBits I have this piped to ````Where-Object { ($_.employeenumber -ne $null)```` condition that I removed then ran. It ran successfully. Do I need to change something in this condition? Should ````$_.employeenumber```` be ````external_id````?

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% follow what you mean. However, "downstream" of the `Select-Object @{n="external_id";e={$_.employeeNumber}},...` there will not be an `employeeNumber` property on objects in the pipeline anymore. If you want to filter out based on a property named `EmployeeNumber` do it *before* the `Select-Object`. If you filter after the `Select-Object`, you would specify `external_id` as the property name.

Comment: @BaconBits you understood! That answers my question. Thanks!